# Connecting to MongoDB with android

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB database in android but I'm having problems. I get:

> I/cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mlab_string], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}

Then i get:

> I/cluster: No server chosen by PrimaryServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=mlab_string, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

Is there a connection being made?
Im using [this](https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver) library as the MongoDB driver as I read that the official driver is not supported by android. I noticed that this library has no been updated for 2 years. Are there any updated alternatives? Are there any alternate free NoSQL database's that officially support android?

I am calling this method in an Asynctask to produce these errors:

```
    fun insert(user: User){
    var client : MongoClient? = null
    try{
        val uri = MongoClientURI("mongodb://Username:Password@mlab_String")
        client = MongoClient(uri)
        val db = client.getDatabase(uri.database)
        val coll = db.getCollection("collname")
        coll.insertOne(user.returnAsDoc())
    }catch(e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }finally{
        try{
            client!!.close()
        }catch(e2: Exception){
            e2.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just a thought.... If you want to use mongodb, why not use ParseServer?

Comment: After doing some research into ParseServer, i have decided to give it a go. Seems much better up to now

Answer (score 0):

Things like these (that involve internal connections or unsupported drivers ;-)) are usually pretty hard (or even impossible) on Android.

Since you asked for alternatives, I suggest http://objectbox.io/.
Afaik it's implemented as a native NoSQL database, which makes it pretty fast.
You can basically store the Objects directly and don't have to convert them to Documents first.